# Reportviewer control toolbar in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, html, css, reporting-services, reportviewer

I am using Reportviewer control in ASP.NET pages.
It was running well in till date, today I changed some styling of page and the Reportviewer toolbar is now distorted.
How to fix that?
[image]

Comment: I guess it's inheriting your styles, just check where computed style comes from using the browser itself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its mainly because you have declared  Global Style in css.

Comment: Thanks Exor, I fixed it. There was a problem with attributes set in global Table css